# what is address of msg.sender when webjs proxy contract instance call logic contract abi?

Tags: solidity

In my test demo, I deployed a proxy at this [proxy contract address](https://testnet.hecoinfo.com/address/0x481bd4e77ed82a8cf5e60da2b0a667181917c73e#code), and I have [a logic contract](https://testnet.hecoinfo.com/address/0x5405E8f3a4C166D00EA44bB51E1BceC10B3b0da2#code). When I used web3.js  create a proxy contract at proxy contract with logic ABI, then call the logic contract function ***withdraw(address _recipient, address _tokenAddr, uint256 _amount) onlyWhitelisted public***, what's the address of msg.sender in the called function of logic function? It's the user address or the address of proxy contract? In my logic contract, there is a public mapping(address => bool) whitelist. I want use whitelist[msg.sender] to check whether the original use address is in the whitelist. I have added my user address to the whitelist.But whitelist[msg.sender] always return false when via proxy contract to interactive with logic contract.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

The proxy contract uses `delegatecall()` native function to redirect the request. Which also passes the original `msg.sender`.

> *what's the address of msg.sender in the called function of logic function*

It's the original address that calls the proxy.

---

> *But whitelist[msg.sender] always return false when via proxy contract to interactive with logic contract.*

When you're using a proxy contract, all storage values are stored on the proxy address - not on the logic address. So when you're querying value of `whitelist[msg.sender]`, you need to use the ABI of the logic contract but **the address of the proxy**.

Comment: Yes, I have used the ABI of the logic contract and the address of the proxy, but that in that case,it failed in the withdraw(address _recipient, address _tokenAddr, uint256 _amount) onlyWhitelisted public function, the onlyWhitelisted make the transaction revert.Do you mean that I should  use the ABI of the logic contract but the address of the proxy to add address to the whitelist, then the data  would stored in the proxy contract. in the logic contract only owner could add address to whitelist, what can I modify make that work correctly?

Comment: @crazytom "Do you mean that I should use the ABI of the logic contract but the address of the proxy to add address to the whitelist, then the data would stored in the proxy contract" Yes, exactly... Since only the owner can add the address, you need to invoke the function to "add address to the whitelist" from the owner address, and through the proxy.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the modifier `onlyOwner`, but if I call "add address to the whitelist" from owner address via the proxy, the transaction reverted. If I just use logic address and logic ABI to call that function, it will work well. I will modify the condition. Thanks from the bottom of my heart. You did do me a favor!